# What does discourse AN 9.37 describe?

Tags: sutras, jhana

From [AN 9.37](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN9_37.html):

> Ven. Ānanda said, “It’s amazing, friends, it’s astounding, how the
> Blessed One who knows & sees, the worthy one, rightly self-awakened,
> has attained & awakened to an opening [in a confining place]1 for the
> purification of beings, for the overcoming of sorrow & lamentation,
> for the disappearance of pain & distress, for the attainment of the
> right method, & for the realization of unbinding, where the eye will
> be, and those forms, and yet one will not be sensitive to that
> dimension; where the ear will be, and those sounds… where the nose
> will be, and those aromas… where the tongue will be, and those
> flavors… where the body will be, and those tactile sensations, and yet
> **one will not be sensitive to that dimension.**”

Why does the passage omit the sixth-sense sphere, intellect-idea?  Usually the use of ellipsis for repetitive text, but not in this discourse.  Does this discourse describe intra-jhana or a state after jhana?

As an adjunct, MN43 says this about the state after *cessation of perception and feeling*:

> Friend, what is the difference between a dead body and a bhikkhu
> attained to the cessation of perceptions and feelings? Friend, in a
> dead body the bodily determination (in and out breath) has ceased and
> is appeased The verbal determination (thinking and pondering) has
> ceased and is appeased The mental determination (feeling and
> perception) has ceased and is appeased. Vitality is exhausted. The
> heat has extinguished, and the mental faculties have broken up.
>
> Of the bhikkhu attained to the cessation of perceptions and feelings,
> the bodily determintion has ceased and is appeased. The verbal
> determination has ceased and is appeased. The mental determination has
> ceased is appeased. Vitality is not exhausted. The heat is not
> extinguished. **The mental faculties are very clear.** Friend, this is
> the difference between a dead body and of one attained to the
> cessation of perceptions and feelings.

If AN 9:37 is not describing jhana, does MN.43 describe a state different than AN 9.37?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passage in AN 9.37 omits the sixth sense sphere because the sixth sense sphere is conscious/percipient of the immaterial spheres:

> [Ven. Udāyin:] “When not sensitive to that dimension, my friend, one
> is percipient of what?”
>
> [Ven. Ānanda:] “There is the case where, with the complete
> transcending of perceptions of (physical) form, with the disappearance
> of perceptions of resistance, and not attending to perceptions of
> multiplicity, (perceiving,) ‘Infinite space,’ one enters & remains in
> the dimension of the infinitude of space. Percipient in this way, one
> is not sensitive to that dimension [i.e, the dimensions of the five
> physical senses].
>
> And further, with the complete transcending of the dimension of the
> infinitude of space, (perceiving,) ‘Infinite consciousness,’ one
> enters & remains in the dimension of the infinitude of consciousness.
> Percipient in this way, too, one is not sensitive to that dimension.
>
> And further, with the complete transcending of the dimension of the
> infinitude of consciousness, (perceiving,) ‘There is nothing,’ one
> enters & remains in the dimension of nothingness. Percipient in this
> way, too, one is not sensitive to that dimension.

MN 43 does not say: "*The mental faculties are very clear*". When MN 43 uses the term 'faculties', it is referring the five physical sense faculties, as follows:

> Friend, there are these five faculties each with a separate range, a
> separate domain, and they do not experience one another's range &
> domain: the eye-faculty, the ear-faculty, the nose-faculty, the
> tongue-faculty, & the body-faculty.
>
> Friend, what can be known with the purified intellect-consciousness
> divorced from the five [sense] faculties? Friend, with the purified intellect-consciousness divorced from the
> five faculties the dimension of the infinitude of space can be known
> [as] 'infinite space.' The dimension of the infinitude of
> consciousness can be known [as] 'infinite consciousness.' The
> dimension of nothingness can be known [as] 'There is nothing.'
>
> But in the case of a monk who has attained the cessation of perception & feeling, his bodily fabrications have ceased & subsided, his verbal fabrications ... his mental fabrications have ceased & subsided, his vitality is not exhausted, his heat has not subsided, & his [five sense] faculties are exceptionally clear.
>
> [MN 43](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.043.than.html)

Also, the translation "clear" sounds misleading because it gives the impression the five sense faculties are lucid & conscious. The Pali is [vippasanna](https://suttacentral.net/define/vippasanna), which can mean 'pure', in the sense of 'clean', rather than 'lucid' or 'sinless'.

[image]

Comment: so to be clear, you are saying AN9:37 is describing jhana, and not a post-jhana state

Comment: No. There are only four jhanas, the 1st with vitakka, vicara, piti, sukha, ekaggata, 2nd, 3rd & 4th. AN 9.37 is describing arupa spheres, which occur after the four jhanas. In common speech, AN 9.37 is describing the 5th, 6th & 7th 'jhana'; even though they are not called 'jhana' in the suttas.

Comment: that's what i thought but i was reading as if it was post-jhana....